# AngularJS - Why can't my expression access my model

Tags: angularjs

I have validated all of the JSON objects & they have been successfully added to the VoteCtrl's $scope (see right). From what I can tell my expressions should select the desired data out of my JSON model. So my question is, why isn't this working & what am I missing here?

[image: the scopes should render the empty navigation on the left]

```
                    <!-- National -->
                    <li ng-repeat="nationalHeader in votingTopics" class="nav-header">
                        {{nationalHeader[0].name}}
                    </li>

                    <li ng-repeat="nationalTopic in votingTopics" class="active">
                        <a href="{{nationalTopic.National.topicLink}}">
                            {{nationalTopic.National.topicTitle}}
                        </a>
                    </li>


                    <!-- State -->
                    <li ng-repeat="stateHeader in votingTopics" class="nav-header">
                        {{stateHeader[0]}}
                    </li>

                    <li ng-repeat="stateTopic in votingTopics">
                        <a href="{{stateTopic.State.California.topicLink}}">
                            {{stateTopic.State.California.topicTitle}}
                        </a>
                    </li>


                    <!-- City -->
                    <li ng-repeat="cityHeader in votingTopics" class="nav-header">
                        {{cityHeader[0]}}
                    </li>

                    <li ng-repeat="cityTopic in votingTopics">
                        <a href="{{cityTopic.State.California.Sacramento.City.topicLink}}">
                            {{cityTopic.State.California.Sacramento.City.topicTitle}}
                        </a>
                    </li>


                    <!-- County -->
                    <li ng-repeat="countyHeader in votingTopics" class="nav-header">
                        {{countyHeader[0]}}
                    </li>

                    <li ng-repeat="countyTopic in votingTopics">
                        <a href="{{countyTopic.County.topicLink}}">
                            {{countyTopic.County.topicTitle}}
                        </a>
                    </li>`
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'it isn't working'? Do you get the wrong data? Do you get an error message? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: No, I get none of those. Nothing is happening at all (on the left), but the scopes are showing up correctly when I inspect using the Batarang DevTools extension (on the right) & according to those scopes my templating expression should successfully select the desired data.

Comment: What does your `VoteCtrl` look like? Also, could you perhaps create a minimal version on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMvEwOZvv4LuONNXIfTm) - I also included the routes that specify the view/controller relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling getting the property of your object correctly.  Try the following in your `National` section:

```
<!-- National -->
<li ng-repeat="nationalHeader in votingTopics" class="nav-header">
    {{ nationalHeader.National[0].name }}
</li>

<li ng-repeat="nationalTopic in votingTopics">
    <a href="{{nationalTopic.National.topicLink}}">
        {{nationalTopic.National[0].topicTitle}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank You! How would I go about selecting the state > california > topicTitle?

Comment: You need to think about your data model as it doesn't really make sense to call nationalTopic.National[0] inside of a repeat.  Anyways, to get topicTitle, you need to do: `stateTopic.State[0].California[0].topicTitle`.